# contextFilter not working for multivalue fields in solr suggestor

Tags: solr, solrj, autosuggest

I am trying to use context filter in Solr Suggestor component but the field which I want to use as contextField is a multi-value field. I am getting good response with a single value field but it is failing for multi value field. 
My solrConfig for Suggestor is as shown below :

```
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">displaySuggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">autoComplete</str>
        <str name="payloadField">displayName</str>
        <str name="weightField">rolledUpCount</str>
        <str name="contextField">ancestors</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">textSuggest</str>
        <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>     
    </lst>
</searchComponent>
```

Here ancestors is a multi-value field. Please let me know if this can be used somehow as contextField. Thanks in advance!